# Two ImageView can not display the images from the camera simultaneously

Tags: android, image, android-intent, camera, imageview

I'm new to android, Now I still building an app that consist with Two Activities First is LoginPage and it works well, the second is UserPage the problem starts here. I create Two ImageView on UserPage, what I want is

1. Click on the ImageView
2. Take a picture from a Camera
3. save it to selected ImageView

When I Click the First ImageView and save the picture from camera it works well, The Problem starts when I click the second imageview, when I take a picture and save it to second imageview, the picture in first imageview is gone

This is my code :
user.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/image1"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

UserPage.java

```
public class UserPage extends Activity {


ImageView imageView1, imageView2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user);

    imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
    imageView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);               
        }
    });
    imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2);
    imageView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent ii = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(ii, 2);                  
        }
    });

}//OnCreate

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
    int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Bitmap userImage = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode){
    case 1:
       if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

          Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
          userImage = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
          imageView1.setImageBitmap(userImage);
       }//if resultCode Case 1
       break;
    case 2:
       if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            userImage = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            imageView2.setImageBitmap(userImage);

        }//if resultCode Case 2

      }//Switch 

   }//onActivityResult  
}//UserPage
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.pramana.report"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"        
    />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature> 

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.pramana.report.UserPage"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Please Help, I've already search and try some of suggestion like
[Take multiple images with camera and insert into multiple diffefent imageViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472798/take-multiple-images-with-camera-and-insert-into-multiple-diffefent-imageviews)
but it did not work

Sorry for my bad English I'm not too good in English

Comment: It did not work either, ImageView1 still lost the image when I save Image to ImageView2 maybe you can give me example, just in case I miss your point

Answer (score 0):

try this its working:

*global declaration*

```
ImageView iv1 ,iv2;
private static Bitmap userImage1,userImage2;
```

*click listener for both Imageview*

```
iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);    
        }
    });

    iv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i, 2);    
        }
    });
```

*onActivityResult code*

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
    int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode){
    case 1:
       if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
           userImage1 = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
          Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
          userImage1 = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
          iv1.setImageBitmap(userImage1);
       }//if resultCode Case 1
       break;
    case 2:
       if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           userImage2 = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            userImage2 = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            iv2.setImageBitmap(userImage2);

        }//if resultCode Case 2

      }//Switch 

   }//onActivityResult
```

Comment: It did not work, I created userImage1 and userImage2 then replace my userImage but still image in ImageView1 is gone when I set Image in ImageView2, any other suggestion?

Comment: try with declaring your both bitmap object static as pointed by sherin

Comment: It no use either, any other suggestion?

Comment: have look at my ans i have updated it with working code at myside.

Comment: Ugh its still the same like before

Comment: check is your `static bitmap userImage1` value is null? when you try to capture 2nd image.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS  :

private static Bitmap sImageView1 =null;

private static Bitmap sImageView2 =null;

private static Uri image_uri;

```
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      SavedInstanceState mSavedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;

    if (mSavedInstanceState==null){
        sImageView1=null;
        sImageView2=null;
    }


            imageView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) { 

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    Uri fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
                    image_uri = fileUri;
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);       
               }
            });

        }

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (sImageView1 !=null) {
        imageView1.setImageBitmap(userImage);
    } 
    if (sImageView2 !=null) {
        imageView2.setImageBitmap(userImage);
    } 


}

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data) {

        //UPDATE THIS CODE
            switch(requestCode){
             case 1:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){


                    sImageView1=decodeScaledBitmapFromSdCard(image_uri.getPath(), 200, 200);

//SAVE YOUR IMAGE IN A SHARED PREFERENCES OR IN ANY LOCAL DATABASE
                    RotateBitmap(sImageView1, 0);

                    //imageView1.setImageBitmap(sImageView1);  

                }//if resultCode Case 1
            break;


            }//Switch 
        }



public Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);

    sImageView1 = source;
    sImageView1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);

    imageView1.setImageBitmap(sImageView1);
    imageView1.setAdjustViewBounds(true);


    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

Comment: I tried to edit like yours but the app is stopped when i tried to click ImageView1, any other suggestion sherin?

Comment: @Pramana Then what was that error.First you update your imageview1

Comment: Fatal Exception: main, java.lang.NullPointerException: file

Comment: What I realized is it's even I'm not taking the image the imageView1 is gone, I mean when i click ImageView2 and the when the camera show up I press back button and image in ImageView1 is gone, is the trouble comes when create new Intent?

Comment: @Pramana  Ok. Then i think you are not saving your first captured image.You need to save image that which you take first because when you try to took the next image without saving the previous image your activity will restart so it will work like a new one only.

Comment: tq for your response, is there any reference for me to see and learn?

Comment: Tq Sherin it's already solved, saving image in shared preferences solved the problem. Even it took a little while but it worked very well thanks again

Comment: @Pramana That sounds good. Post your answer or up vote the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sherin and Yograj Shinde, the solution is I have to save the activity before start a new one. Here is my code :

UserPage.Java

```
public class UserPage extends Activity {

ImageView iv1 ,iv2;
private static Bitmap userImage1,userImage2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user);

    if(savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        userImage1 = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("userImage1");
    }

    iv1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
    iv2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2);

    iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);    
        }
    });

    iv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i, 2);    
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(userImage1 != null)
    {
        iv1.setImageBitmap(userImage1);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
   savedInstanceState.putParcelable("userImage1", userImage1);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
    int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode){
    case 1:
       if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
          userImage1 = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
          Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
          userImage1 = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
          iv1.setImageBitmap(userImage1);
       }//if resultCode Case 1
       break;
    case 2:
       if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           userImage2 = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            userImage2 = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            iv2.setImageBitmap(userImage2);

        }//if resultCode Case 2

      }//Switch 

   }//onActivityResult 


}//Class UserPage
```

The idea here is when the start a new activity you must save your last activity to prevent from loss. That's why I using

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
   savedInstanceState.putParcelable("userImage1", userImage1);
}
```

to save the data before start new activity, and use onStart() to set ImageView when the new activity start
This article will help you to understand :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html 
[How to use onSavedInstanceState example please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525698/how-to-use-onsavedinstancestate-example-please)

Note:
The program still need a lot of improvement because it's not finished yet but I hope it will help others